# How to load data in repeater on page scroll

Tags: asp.net, ajax, repeater

I have one repeater with textbox and image button i need to load data when page is scroll simple html data i will load but how to assign commandtext and commandargument on image button when load data on page scroll.

Thanks,
Jackson.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post your code? What have you tried?

Comment: i need to load data when page scroll like facebook but on repeater i have textbox and image button so how can i set command argument on it when page scroll.